# ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework select count inner join another table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, count, inner-join

I am writing an ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework app.

I have 2 tables with a relationship 0-to-many. I have to do a select from the first table and also retrieve the `count()` of the second tables with different filters.

In Ansi SQL is more or less like this.

```
select 
    *,
    convert(varchar(3), (select count(User_id) 
                         from ActivityGroups G with(nolock) 
                         where A.Activity_id = G.Activity_id 
                           and G.ProcessState_id = 1)) + '  (' + 
    convert(varchar(3), (select count(User_id) 
                         from ActivityGroups G with(nolock) 
                         where A.Activity_id = G.Activity_id 
                           and G.ProcessState_id = 2)) + ')' as Members 
from 
    Activities A
```

It retrieves a string like `5(3)` under name `members`.

The LINQ query so far:

```
IEnumerable<ActivitySearch> viewModel = (from activities in _db.Activities
                        .Where(p => p.ProcessState_id == Security.APPROVED)
                        .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreationDate)
                        select new ActivitySearch
                        {
                          Activity_Id = activities.Activity_Id,
                          User_id = activities.User_id,
                          Type = activities.Type,
                          SeekName = activities.SeekName,
                        });
```

I do not how add the `Count()` to another table in return value.

Thanks

Comment: I *highly* doubt that `with(nolock)` would be considered `Ansi SQL` ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "let" keyword in the query.

```html
 var viewModel = from activities in _db.Activities
                        let ag1 = activities.ActivityGroups.Where(i => i.ProcessState_Id == 1).Count()
                        where p.ProcessState_id == Security.APPROVED
                        order by p.CreationDate descening
                        select new ActivitySearch
                        {
                          Activity_Id = activities.Activity_Id,
                          User_id = activities.User_id,
                          Type = activities.Type,
                          SeekName = activities.SeekName,
                          Group1Count = ag
                        };
```

Essentially the let keyword issues a subquery like your example above.  Just be careful how you craft the query because it can lead to performance issues if not careful.

Comment: You've got a typo there (`ag1` - `ag`). Also, I've experienced that using `let` often causes EF to use outer joins instead of inner joins for other navigation properties (don't know why). Although there are no other navigation properties here, I'd only use `let` if it reduces repetitive code. You could also write `Group1Count = activities.ActivityGroups.....`.

Comment: Yeah that would be fine or `let = _db.ActivityGroups.Where(i => i.ActivityID == activities.Activity_Id && i.ProcessState_Id == 1);` as an alternative.  I've not had problems using let with navigation properties - I haven't experienced the outer join issue but there is a chance that certain types of statements may cause that.